# spring boot microservice framework how to call another microservice from one microservice

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build a new application with spring boot microservice framework. I have tried some demo. The existing demo is too simple, doesn't introduce how to call another service from one service. Should still going through http, or should going through RPC? If going RPC, which RPC framework support?

Comment: Up to you entirely. Lots of people us HTTP - REST/SOAP. Lots of people use messaging - RabbitMQ has excellent support in Spring Boot. Some people us frameworks like Akka to deal with distribution; but I'm not sure to what extent that integrates with Spring Boot. Still others use raw sockets and custom protocols with UDP/multicast for clustering support. Still others use shared objects through the likes of Hazelcast and Teracotta. Basically, the number of approaches is **huge** and without some criteria the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. so if the performance is not an issue, I would like use http, since it is simple. d

Answer (score 2):

The way of integrating among services depends on numerous factors, like synchronicity/asynchronicity, load that will be generated, etc. The most popular (I guess) way of integration is REST-based one. Because you tagged your question with `spring` I would recommend using declarative REST client - Feign that is very well described [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-feign). You can use message brokers as well, which are also very well abstracted by Spring Cloud Stream - you can read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/). I think that more in depth discussion should be based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If another micro-services are exposing the REST API , then you can simple use [jersey client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)

or [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to call them.

Comment: Or Spring Rest support via `RestTemplate` - likely more sensible as the OP explicitly mentions Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Use RestTemplate or [FeignClient](https://javatechonline.com/how-to-implement-feign-client-in-spring-boot-microservices/) for Synchronous Spring based Rest api's. Use any message tools for Asynchronous calls like Kafka, ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ.